# How to pause and resume goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am trying to pause and resume groutine. I understand I can `sleep` the run, but I am looking for is like a button "pause/resume" rather than a timer.

Here is my attempt. I am using the blocking feature of channel to pause, and `select` to switch what to execute based on channel value. However, the output is always `Running` in my case.

```
func main() {
    ctx := wctx{}
    go func(ctx wctx) {
        for {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            select {
            case <-ctx.pause:
                fmt.Print("Paused")
                <-ctx.pause
            case <-ctx.resume:
                fmt.Print("Resumed")
            default:
                fmt.Print("Running \n")
            }
        }
    }(ctx)

    ctx.pause <- struct{}{}
    ctx.resume <- struct{}{}
}

type wctx struct {
    pause  chan struct{}
    resume chan struct{}
}
```

Comment: There's the only one method to pause and resume goroutine, but this functionality lives inside runtime https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/HACKING.md#synchronization . Otherwise, you can try double lock and double unlock a mutex. Regularly, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `select` with multiple ready cases chooses one pseudo-randomly. So if the goroutine is "slow" to check those channels, you might send a value on both `pause` and `resume` (assuming they are buffered) so receiving from both channels could be ready, and `resume` could be chosen first, and in a later iteration the `pause` when the goroutine should not be paused anymore.

For this you should use a "state" variable synchronized by a mutex. Something like this:

```
const (
    StateRunning = iota
    StatePaused
)

type wctx struct {
    mu    sync.Mutex
    state int
}

func (w *wctx) SetState(state int) {
    w.mu.Lock()
    defer w.mu.Unlock()
    w.state = state
}

func (w *wctx) State() int {
    w.mu.Lock()
    defer w.mu.Unlock()
    return w.state
}
```

Testing it:

```
ctx := &wctx{}
go func(ctx *wctx) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        switch state := ctx.State(); state {
        case StatePaused:
            fmt.Println("Paused")
        default:
            fmt.Println("Running")
        }
    }
}(ctx)

time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
ctx.SetState(StatePaused)
time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
ctx.SetState(StateRunning)
time.Sleep(2 * time.Millisecond)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oDkXrsv5_lA)):

```
Running
Running
Running
Paused
Paused
Paused
Running
Running
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your channels, remember that reads from nil channels always blocks.

A `select` with a `default` case never blocks.

Here is a modified version of your program, that fixes the above mentioned issues:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := wctx{
        pause:  make(chan struct{}),
        resume: make(chan struct{}),
    }

    go func(ctx wctx) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.pause:
                fmt.Println("Paused")
            case <-ctx.resume:
                fmt.Println("Resumed")
            }

            fmt.Println("Running")
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }(ctx)

    ctx.pause <- struct{}{}
    ctx.resume <- struct{}{}
}

type wctx struct {
    pause  chan struct{}
    resume chan struct{}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need pass by reference here? I think I am not modifying any value of the struct so I do not need to?